# Decode response body from feign client to MyObject

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, response, feign

I have created a Feign client StorageClient like as shown below:

```kotlin
@Headers(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT + ": " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
interface StorageApi {
    @RequestLine("GET /api/v1/files/{fileId}")
    fun getFileMeta(@Param("fileId") fileId: Long): Response
}
```

```kotlin
@Service
class StorageClient(private val storageApi: StorageApi) {
    fun getFile(fileId: Long): StorageFile = storageApi.getFileMeta(fileId)
}
```

In addition to the StorageClient client, the `getFileMeta()` method (interface `StorageApi`) is also used to check for the the status (method `isFileExists()`):

```kotlin
fun isFileExists(fileId: Long): Boolean = storageApi.getFileMeta(fileId).status() != 404
```

For this reason, I cannot write explicitly:

```
@RequestLine("GET /api/v1/files/{fileId}")
fun getFileMeta(@Param("fileId") fileId: Long): StorageFile
```

How can I decode the Response body so that it is possible to return an object of type `StorageFile` from the `getFile()` (class `StorageClient`) method? Or maybe there is some way to work with both the `status` of the received `Response` and its `body`?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a little late, you can decode the body manually using a JSON deserializer such as Jackson:

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

val json = IOUtils.toString(response.body().asInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8)
val storageFile = ObjectMapper().readValue(json, StorageFile::class.java)
```

Make sure to add Jackson as dependency. For example in your pom.xml if you're using maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>..</version>
</dependency>
```

An in-depth tutorial on Jackson is available here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial.

---

**Important notice:** Make sure to call `response.close()` when you're done. Otherwise this will lead to a resource leak.